# BIND file not working

Tags: debian, bind

recently changed the bind file adding some comments with the character "#" which is the wrong one I guess because since the my website is inaccessible.

So I change it back, incrementing the serial number but by error I've incremented it to the 32 instead of the 31 but It shouldn't pose any problem. It's been two hours and it's still doesn't work.

Did I miss something ? I'm starting to get quite worried :(

PS : of course I reloaded the bind server every time.

Edit : I've also done the command bind -v by error, I don't know it's effects.

Edit : My predecessor didn't configure the bind log files so I tried to, my named.conf.options file is :

```
options {

    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };

    listen-on { any; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 213.186.33.199; };

    allow-query-cache { 127.0.0.1; 213.186.33.199; };
    additional-from-cache no;
};

logging {

    channel default_log {

        file "/var/log/bind/error.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity warning;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-category yes;
    };

    category default{
    default_log;
  };
};
```

But my logs are empty...

Edit : here is my db.domain.com file :

```
$TTL    3600
domain.com.       IN      SOA     serverid.kimsufi.com. myemail@gmail.com. (
                        2013090101  ; Serial
                        1200        ; Refresh
                        180     ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                        3600 )      ; Negative caching TTL
;
;NAMESERVERS
;
                IN      NS      serverid.kimsufi.com.
                IN      NS      ns.kimsufi.com.
;
;Nodes in domain
;
imap            IN      A       IPSERVER
domain.com.       IN      MX      10 mail.domain.com.
domain.com.       IN      A       94.23.52.112
mail            IN      A       IPSERVER
mysql           IN      A       IPSERVER
pop             IN      A       IPSERVER
pop3            IN      A       IPSERVER
smtp            IN      A       IPSERVER
sql             IN      A       IPSERVER
www             IN      A       IPSERVER
;
;Subdomains
;
subdomain1          IN      A       IPSERVER
...
subdomain12          IN      A       IPSERVER
;*.domain.com.    IN      A       IPSERVER
```

Comment: Having a look at `/var/log/syslog` might help, since bind usually drops its errors over there AND will even tell you, **which** line in your file is buggy.

Comment: I checked my bind9 on wheezy, there's no logging configured in `/etc/bind/*`, so just try and remove that part from named.conf and restart (not reload, this time, just to be safe) your bind9.

Comment: Done, no change at the moment. Do you have by any chance a file named.conf.log ?

Comment: I think the default log target is *syslog*, at least on Debian.

Comment: I've got `Aug 31 18:27:51 ks3098028 pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=admin@kimsufi.com, ip=[::ffff:202.149.117.38]
Aug 31 18:27:51 ks3098028 pop3d: authentication error: Input/output error` repeatedly with different user : spam@kimsufi.com, test@kimsufi.com, ...

Comment: Here's a more relevant part of the logs, sorry I cannot publish them in a answer : http://pastebin.com/pwWmD10P

Comment: Rather then simply waiting for things to propogate / start working, try using tools like nslookup to query your local server directly and see if it is responding as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't understand the problem, but I changed the name of my db.domaine.com file, created a new one, paste the content in it and well it's rolling again !